# Can age limit be an issue for postdoc in China?

Tags: postdocs, university, legal-issues, age, china

I have got post doc position in China a year back when I was 34. Due to Covid situations, my permit expired before and now lab fellow is planning again to apply for work permit but my age is 35 now.  Can someone tell me I will get the work permit or visa?  Or due to 35 above age,  would I be denied?

Comment: China doesn't grant work permits to people older than 34?

Comment: It is mentioned on Chinese university website that they do not consider people with age over 35 for post docs. I have offer letter issued a year before but need to apply for permit again.

Comment: That's not the same as getting a visa.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/149518/17254

Comment: I hope so.. But my contract is also updated now that's showed my age is above 35 and PhD with more than 3 years.. So I want an authentic information if it's get approved this time by the university or foreign permit issuance office?